Get all articles from specific wikipedia Portal
I'm trying to put together a list of all articles under the Portal:Water

(e.g. json "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water", "title": "Heavy water" ).

As far as I know, there is no direct page listing all the articles that derive from Portal:Water.  Thus, I decided to check the top category (Category:Water) and all its sub-categories (multiple levels) available in Portal:Water.

I tried running a query (MediaWiki) to fetch category members but only retrieved the top-level categories (45). Sandbox query result.

I have also tried with Petscan (testing with depth=1), but:

I don't know how to choose the optimal depth (info: for depth >5 I query using the subcategories from lvl1 e.g. Water by city)

verify the number of the articles retrieved-number of existing articles in Portal:Water.




If anyone knows how to pull a complete list, including all subcategories ( their subcategories, their sub(sub)categories and so on), I’d really appreciate the guidance.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT: I can get the tree for all categories (depth = 1), but I need all the categories and their subcategories : e.g. Water > Forms of water>Clouds>Cloud and fog physics

The question is, what are the articles under Portal:Water for you? Portals are sites that serve to present a certain topic but do not necessarily include all articles on that topic. The main organizational component of Wikipedia is the category. Articles from individual categories can be listed using the PetScan tool. Still, it may happen that there will also be articles that do not fit under the topic "water," and it will be necessary to remove them manually.

I believe the feature "What links here" is what you want. This is a default feature in Mediawiki system.
For example, to get all the pages which have a portal:Water, you can navigate to this URL:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Portal%3AWater?hidetrans=1&hideimages=1 

Or, for a quick solution, you can simply navigate to the search bar in English Wikipedia, then type linksto:"Portal:Water" then when you click enter, it will retrieve all the pages with that portal.
